# .Foreach showing correct iterations, but repeating same value in each

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

I am creating a financial calculation in PHP which requires that I draw data from the database, apply various calculations to determine the number of months and the insurance premium paid per month, and then echo each month's result.

What is happening is that the foreach is returning the correct number of rows, but repeating the last one for each iteration, so all rows are identical.

I am far from a php fundi and have spent 3 days searching through forums, manuals etc. and have not been able to find the issue. Some articles that might have had the answer, were just completely over my head.

Any assistance on this would be HUGELY appreciated!!

The code:

```
$grosstotal =   array(); 

for ($i=1; $i<=$totaldiff; $i++) 
{

if ($i == '1') { 
$start = $docraw; 
}else {
$realdoc = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($docraw)));
$start = $realdoc; 
}

$days_between = round(abs($end - $start) / 86400); 
$contribution_core = round(abs($days_between) / 30.42); 
$mca = -floor($contribution_core/12);
$mcb = ($escalation+100)/100;
$months_contribution = $current_premium*(pow($mcb,$mca)); 

$grosstotal[] = $months_contribution;
}

foreach($grosstotal as $months_contribution) {
echo  $months_contribution . '<br>';
  $gtotal = array_sum($grosstotal);
}
```

$totaldiff in my test case = 38, so the result should be 38 months (rows) returned, each showing the value for that month. My $months_contribution for the final month is 4000. This first row is not showing at all. Each 12 months should reflect a different amount because the premium goes up every year. In this case it is not changing at all apart from the first row.

When I added $i to my echo statement, it shows as 38 on every row, which I think indicates that $i is not incrementing, but purely using its final value.

The result I am getting is:

```
66.4009861824<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
3005.25920361<br>
```

The result should be:
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,005.26
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,305.79
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
3,636.36
4,000.00
4,000.00

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the solution but two things:

- It shows 38 always because your echo in the foreach is after the for closing }
- Why you uses '1' instead 1 at if ($i == '1') { ?

Comment: Thanks for responding but the echo is within the {} braces for the foreach statement. It is outside the initial 'for' statement but not the foreach. If I put it inside the for statement, then the reiteration itself keeps repeating.

Comment: I have been playing with what you said all day and finally got at least part of my problem figured out. You were right about the closing }, but it only works if I do away with the foreach statement altogether and simply have my echo inside before the } at the end of the for statement. Which then revealed a different problem in my code related to the date calculation and formatting within the iteration. It's a start. Thank you!